# Density property for Sobolev spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

My question is as follows:  is the space $ C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \mathcal{C}) $ dense in $ H^1( \mathbb{R}^3) $ where $ \mathcal{C} $ is the circle $ \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x^2 + y^2 = 1,\ z=0 \}$?  In the radial case (i.e. $ H^1_{rad}( \mathbb{R}^3) $ ), does the proof become simpler and can we construct a sequence of approximations explicitely?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Of course not, the result you get by completion is simply $H^1_0(\mathbb R^3\setminus C)$, the set of $H^1$ functions vanishing on the boundary.
This question would be better suited for [Math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/), vote to close

Comment: I'm sorry for the mistake in writing. In fact $ \mathbb{R}^2 $ should be  $ \mathbb{R}^3 $

Comment: what's $C$, then? you can edit your question after it's posted, please do so.

Comment: You edited the question so I edited my answer. The statement is the same and you still get $H^1_0$